# ODE WAR examples wont run UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: tomcat7, orchestration, apache-ode

I am trying to install and understand ODE.

I set up Tomcat7 no problem
I set up ODE WAR distribution
I copied the examples folder as per instructions.

Then I ran it, and it failed.
Then I RTM some more and saw

The sendsoap executable can be found in the distribution bin directory. The urls should be updated according to the address defined in the WSDL file for the process service.

The executable script using the command line given fires an exception.

could not find or load main class org.apache.ode.tools.sendsoap.cline.HttpSoapSender

latest version.
If there is some update to URLs required there are no directions to do that anywhere in the install instructions. Given that new users do installs this has to be one of the most brain dead careless instruction sets I have read in years regardless of the fix. But can someone enlighten me?

Just to be clear, the startup screen on port 8080 comes up just fine.

Comment: What does "ODE" mean to you? The [tag:ode] tag that you used is about ordinary differential equations.

Comment: http://ode.apache.org/index.html
Name collision.

Answer (score 1):

The command line tools seem to have some class path issues. I'd suggest to use SoapUI instead, it provides a better UX as well.

**Update**: Quickstart to verify the installation:

For a simple test, just copy the helloworld2 example from the dist package to tomcat/webapps/ode/processes. The process should then appear in the web console. Copy the Axis2 WSDL URL of the helloworld process http://localhost:8080/ode/deployment/services/, which is most likely
http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/helloWorld?wsdl. Open SoapUI, start a new SOAP project, paste the WSDL URL into the "Initial WSDL" form and create the project. SoapUI will create sample request "Request 1" for the hello operation. Double click, play with the content and invoke the method using the green "play" button.

Comment: Is there a video or description you can share that will test this? I am looking for a simple straight forward how-to with no fuss or messy explanations. Just an affirmation check that the thing is installed correctly and works well enough to move on to the next step. Which will be installing Postgresql if that database is supported, the docs dont say it is but the included drivers have it. In fact it seems to me as though the web and training stuff for this product are sub standard for an apache product, even for an incubator. I might need to recommend Apache re-think this project's status.

Comment: No, unfortunately we have no video or description for that, I'll update my answer with a basic quickstart. We also appreciate any documentation improvements via mailinglists. Using PostgreSQL was IIRC a bit tricky, I'd suggest to ask at user@ode.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a build problem the JAR files in the lib directory of the 1.3.6 WAR/JBI distributions don't work ([Bug Report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ODE-1030)). Use the 1.3.5 distribution instead until this is fixed.